# Assert_difference in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

Is this really the best way?

```
assert_difference('u.point', 10) do
  assert_difference('u.point_logs.count') do
    assert_difference('a.point', 5) do
      assert_difference('a.point_logs.count') do
        u.give_points(:description => 'Test', :points => 10.0)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Regards,

Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is the best way if one wants to avoid splitting it up into two blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly encourage you to write more tests to stress specific features. You can write one test to assert the difference on `a` and write one test to assert the difference on `u`.

Comment: You do understand that calling give_points on u changes both u and a at the same time?

Comment: Ok - does that change your recommendation?

Comment: Not really. The test seems too complex for me. I need more context, but the main idea won't change. RSpec has one rule: one assertion per test. This is often impossible, but try to make your best between balancing 1:1 and 4:1.

Comment: That one assertion rule is many times hard to apply in reality indeed (especially in integration tests) and it can also be quite inefficient as tests need to be initialized over and over again. Or does anybody know a way of reusing models initialized in previous tests? Well I guess that is difficult as tests would become order dependent. Maybe a need for a gem? ;-) And/or a separate SO question. ;-)